# Select column without using column name

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to select nth column in a SELECT clause from a table/view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768688/is-there-a-way-to-select-nth-column-in-a-select-clause-from-a-table-view)

How to select first five column of a table without using column name.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?  How do you define `first`?

Comment: What did they say the answer was?

Comment: This question may need to be deleted as an exact <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768688/is-there-a-way-to-select-nth-column-in-a-select-clause-from-a-table-view">duplicate</a>

Comment: Don't forget to credit Ben.Vineyard ;o)

Comment: @JNK I don't need that. Interviewer asked me that.

Comment: @gbn They didn't answer anything perfect. they just said you can do that with some system functions.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite then he/she are morons and you probably shouldn't worry about working there.

Comment: Any other top reason to down vote this question? I hope I would have get the same down vote option when interviewer asked the same question.

Comment: @JNK Now that makes me feel better :-)

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite - I mean there is a way to do it, but it's a garbage question because there is absolutely **no reason** to ever do this in "real life".  Column order is completely irrelevant, and if you don't know what the columns are you shouldn't be querying just a few of them.

Comment: @JNK That's the second time I have been asked this question, but this time in a different frame **Let say I have 100 column in a table and I would like to select 90 of them and I don't want to write 90 column name. How to do that** and today, again, I had been asked same question... so I thought to ask on SO.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite well the "right" answer to that question is to query the system tables like `sys.columns` to build a dynamic sql query.  but that's garbage since it would be far easier just to get the field names from SSMS.

Comment: @JNK I said the same.. That I would drag drop the columns in SSMS and remove the 10 unnecessary columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how do you define 'the first 5 columns'?  alphabetically?

do you just want the column names? or the data from those columns?

i would say this is first a call to the data dictionary to find all the columns, then turn that result into some sql to do the actual select if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL Server you can use Information_Schema.Columns and look at the table_name, column_name and ordinal_position columns to find the first five columns. Then use dynamic SQL to generate an appropriate select statement. Dynamic SQL is generally discouraged...

Answer (score 0):

This will return the first five columns for a table based on the colorder value in syscolumns.

```
SELECT sc.name
FROM sysobjects so
INNER JOIN syscolumns sc
ON so.id = sc.id
WHERE so.name = 'substations'
AND sc.colorder <= 5
ORDER BY sc.colorder
```