# How to read data from certain columns by index in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to C# and SQL and I am using windows forms.

I have Table `MyTable` which has `20` `columns` and let's say we dont know the columns name.

Let's say I want to read data from column number 13.

Anyone knows how can I read all data from a certain `column` based on its index, I mean how to read data from `column` number?

Thank you.

Comment: something like this might be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20992707/8086878

Comment: @ dbajtr . the table name in that answer must be known. In my question the column name is not known, if I know the column name then the issue is solved. the reason why I dont know the column name is because I create it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices.  The first is to read the metadata for the table and determine the names of the columns that you want.

The second is to use `select *` and then choose the nth return value in each row.

However, there is something suspicious about an application that does not want to know columns names.  Accessing columns by position is a bad idea.  In fact, the one place in the SQL language that does it -- using positions in `ORDER BY` -- has been deprecated in the standard.

Comment: Just as a real world example (I'm not OP): I've seen business solutions where a flat file was parsed into a SQL table; and would only then be processed by my application. These tables received sequential names (as they were created on the fly per imported file), and the columns were not named either. I'm not advocating this system, I'm simply arguing its existence.

Comment: @Flater . . . Temporary files used for staging incoming data is clearly different from a robust data model.

Answer (score 1):

When using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`, you can generate a data reader that allows you to approach column values (per row) by their index.

For the purpose of example, I'm assuming you're expecting `string` values, but the solution is analogous for any other type.

```
List<String> column14Values = new List<String>();

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using(var command = new SqlCommand(myQuery, connection))
    {
          var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

          while(reader.Read())
          {
               string theFourteenthColumnValue = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(13);

               column14Values.Add(theFourteenthColumnValue); 
          }
    }
}

return column14Values;
```

---

I would **highly** suggest changing your SQL `SELECT` statement to only return the needed column; which will drastically decrease the amount of data returned from the database.

My solution works, and it directly answers your question; but it is not the most optimal solution for retrieving a single column's data.

Comment: I am really concerned about the query, can you please include the query. thank you.

Comment: @user8074669 How can I know what query you want to run when you haven't even discussed it in your question? I don't know your database, nor its structure. The whole premise of your question seems to be that you are unable to change the query. If you are able to change the query, then you are approaching this problem wrongly and should focus on how to write a query that only returns the needed column; as opposed to trying to read the 14th column from a larger data set. In this case, I would refer you to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)