# How to select the nth column, and order columns' selection in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this huge table upon which I apply a lot of processing (using CTEs), and I want to perform a UNION ALL on 2 particular CTEs.

```
SELECT  *
        , 0 AS orders
        , 0 AS revenue
        , 0 AS units
FROM secondary_prep_cte WHERE purchase_event_flag IS FALSE
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM results_orders_and_revenues_cte
```

I get a `"Column 1164 in UNION ALL has incompatible types : STRING,DATE at [97:5]`

Obviously I don't know the name of the column, and I'd like to debug this but I feel like I'm going to waste a lot of time if I can't pin-point which column is 1164.
I also think this is a problem of the order of columns between the CTEs, so I have 2 questions:

1. How do I identify the 1164th column
2. How do I order my columns before performing the UNION ALL

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768688/is-there-a-way-to-select-nth-column-in-a-select-clause-from-a-table-view) but it is for MSSQL, I am using BigQuery

Comment: Do `create table as select` and compare datatypes of the columns with the same ordinal position. But it is better to specify columns explicitly until you really select from the same source wut with different filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get information from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` but you'll need to create a table or view from the CTE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `project.dataset.secondary_prep_view` as select * from (select 1 as id, "a" as name, "b" as value)
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE  table_name = 'secondary_prep_view';
```

[image]

Comment: Alright, this solves the first question. THe second one is the one posing the real issue with the `UNION ALL`, I can write the columns one by one in the `SELECT` statement, but that is ugly and hard to maintain beyond measure

Comment: @Aetos you might use a query on the first view to get column names in order (`SELECT STRING_AGG(column_name order by ordinal_position) FROM dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE  table_name = 'secondary_prep_view'`) then create the second one using the result to reorder them. Or using dynamic SQL, see [BigQuery Scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting)